# Django - Импорт модели - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, база-данных, django, pycharm, model

Проект на виртуальном окружении. Django 2.0. Python 3.6.2

При попытке импортировать любую модель возникает ошибка Apps aren't loaded yet. Например запускаю скрипт example.py через PyCharm debuger (prntscr.com/it9214):

```
from tracker.models import ProxyItem

Proxy = ProxyItem

Proxy.address = '127.0.0.1:8000'
Proxy.timeout = '0.003'
Proxy.status = 'unchecked'

Proxy.save()
```

И получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/apps/amz_service/tracker/modules/example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tracker.models import ProxyItem
  File "E:\apps\amz_service\tracker\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class ProxyItem(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Roman\amz_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\Roman\amz_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Roman\amz_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class ProxyItem(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='unchecked')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for amz_service project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FILE_DB_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '/tracker/DB/'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*4^99u4d!rtim)rk&6cjl)-ytszxxf8%p_n)s1!zbt@(=cx3q3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*'
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'tracker.apps.TrackerConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'amz_service.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'amz_service.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'amz_service',
        'USER': 'amz_service',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/resources/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for amz_service project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "amz_service.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class TrackerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'tracker'
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запустить example.py напрямую? Этого нельзя делать, не проинициализировав джангу

Comment: Что за example.py? У Django очень чёткие принципы организации кода. Обычно http-запрос приходит в wsgi.py, тот передаёт его в urls.py, оттуда он через цепочку middleware уходит к одному из представлений в views.py, которые уже импортируют и используют модели из models.py

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Да. Забыл добавить:
Запускаю скрипт через PyCharm debuger: http://prntscr.com/it9214

Comment: @РоманДенисенко так нельзя делать. В зависимости от того, что конкретно вам нужно, вы должны использовать один из «официальных» способов запуска своего кода: какое-то из представлений (views) на запущенном сервере, своя команда в management/commands или миграции. Тупо брать и запускать какой-то там непонятный example.py обычно не стоит

Comment: Django - это web-фреймворк, он должен обрабатывать http-запросы. А для всяких сервисных механизмов необходимо использовать [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Разобрался. И в самом деле нельзя запускать скрипты так как я это делал ранее... Через сервер management commands все отработало прекрасно.
Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: @РоманДенисенко вот еще полено будет почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready